# Regular expression to restrict less than <,greater than > and semicolon ; character

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I need a regular expression to restrict the < less than, greater than > and ; semicolon sign.

I have used the below regular expression to restrict the less than and greater than sign but I need to include the semicolon ; sign as well.

```
^[^<><>]+$
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What's the restriction? Completely disallowed or something else?

Comment: Just include it as `^[^;<>]+$`.

Comment: Thanks It Worked !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy to achieve if you read very little about regex. The feature you are using is the *character class* and you can learn more about this here http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Related to your regex is quite simple, in this case you are using a negated character class by `[^...]` so you have just to add the semicolon to it:

```
^[^<>;]+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]